# What would be the most efficient way to check if a JavaScript variable is either falsey, or an empty array or object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a use case where a function receives a variable which could be of various types, including an array or an object reference.

But I want to ignore any variables passed in which are falsey in the usual JavaScript senses, plus I want to treat empty arrays `[]` and empty objects `{}` as also being falsey.

I can see immediately there would be many ways to do this but I'm wondering what would be most efficient assuming a very modern JavaScript implementation and only vanilla JavaScript with no frameworks.

The obvious way is to check if it's an array or an object and check `.length` in the case of an array and `Object.keys(x).length` if it's an object. But considering that some other things which are already falsey are also `typeof` `object` and that empty arrays seem to behave either truthy or falsey depending on how you check, I'm betting that some ways are more efficient and probably more idiomatic too.

Comment: I'll bet you are thinking too much about efficiency - In the *vast* majority of cases, readability > efficiency - anything other than that is almost undeniably, poor design.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: No, it's more curiosity and keeping up to date with what's idiomatic. I only code as a hobby these days.

Comment: As I'm sure you already know, the word "efficient" translates to "most-performant" for most people - perhaps you should edit your title.

Comment: I meant efficient because that's what I'm most curious about. Idiomaticity is less important but still interesting so I only included that in the question body. As "most performant" seems to translate to "most correct and best in some unspecified metric" I try to avoid that term. It's not uncommon in JS for the obvious way to achieve something to be the worst way plus I thought some contributors here might have fun answering this question.

Comment: Oh alright - Ignore my comment then. In my book 'most-performant' is not ambiguous, it means less CPU cycles/less-memory but I'll back off anyway :)

Comment: Also, I'm finding the answer pleasing and the comments informative and educational.

Answer (score 1):

The following should match your criteria (Although it looks ugly).

```
if (
     sth &&                                                     // normal JS coercion
     (!Array.isArray(sth) || sth.length) &&                     // falsify empty arrays
     (Object.getPrototypeOf(sth) !== Object.prototype || Object.keys(sth).length)     // falsify empty objects
   ) 
alert("pass");
```

Tests:

```
sth = [];                 // Don't Pass
sth = {};                 // Don't Pass
sth = null;               // Don't Pass
sth = false;              // Don't Pass
sth = undefined;          // Don't Pass
sth = "";                 // Don't Pass
sth = [1];                // Pass
sth = { a: "" }           // Pass
sth = new Date;           // Pass
sth = "a";                // Pass
sth = function(){}        // Pass
```

Comment: An object created with `Object.create` can be a perfectly proper, non-empty object while having `null` as its prototype

Answer (score 0):

This checks if `sth` is truthy:

```
 if(sth && (typeof sth !== "object" || Object.keys(sth).length))
   alert("passes");
```

Comment: `sth && Object.keys(sth).length` should be enough

Comment: @gurvinder372 an empty array has also alength property ;)

Comment: @JonasW. empty array will also be covered by `Object.keys(sth).length`

Comment: @palash alternatively `JSON.stringify(sth).length > 2`

Comment: Just to be pedantic: this answer doesn't check to see if a value is falsy - it does the opposite.

Comment: @Andy: That's OK sometimes it's easier to test one way than the other for random reasons. But it would be helpful to have a note in the answer I agree.

Comment: I had to unaccept since though the answer is elegant, palaѕн is right that it fails for `new Date()`

Comment: @JonasW. More JS bizareness then! Well I wasn't using Dates in this code but this question has certainly been a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I use this al the time.

```
function IsEmpty(val){
    return (!val || val == "" || (typeof(val) === "object" && Object.keys(val).length == 0) || val === [] || val === null || val === undefined);
}
```

Examples that pass

```
if(IsEmpty(false)){console.log("pass");}
if(IsEmpty("")){console.log("pass");}
if(IsEmpty([])){console.log("pass");}
if(IsEmpty({})){console.log("pass");}
if(IsEmpty(null)){console.log("pass");}
if(IsEmpty()){console.log("pass");}
```

Examples that fail

```
if(IsEmpty(true)){console.log("fail");}
if(IsEmpty("not null")){console.log("fail");}
if(IsEmpty([1])){console.log("fail");}
if(IsEmpty({"a":1})){console.log("fail");}

//!IsEmpty means is not empty
if(!IsEmpty(false)){console.log("fail");}
if(!IsEmpty("")){console.log("fail");}
if(!IsEmpty([])){console.log("fail");}
if(!IsEmpty({})){console.log("fail");}
if(!IsEmpty()){console.log("fail");}
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly, `val==[]` and `val=={}` will always be false

Comment: Good catch @Mikael Lennholm, I made an update that should fix that.